# Is there any events after SQL Server job finished?

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I want to get the latest raw job history and save them in my format after job finished every times.
I have written a stored procedure to get the history with `sp_help_jobhistory`, then format the result, then save them into a new table.

But, when to call this stored procedure?

Is there some event fired when the job finishes?

Maybe there are some others solutions.

Thanks for your comments/answers.

Comment: did you consider running the Stored Procedure as the Last Step in your job? This way, upon success your SP is called.

Comment: Yes, I have consider this. And this solution cannot get the history of current running job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the solution, and it works well.
Step 1: Will call sp BeginHistoryLog, this sp will get the information of job from [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] tabel by job name. And this SP will write the initial data intto JobHistory which log the history message.

Step 2: Will call the sp which do the actual work.

Step 3: Will call SP EndHistoryLog, this SP will get the step2 execution information from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory and INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] by job id and step id. And this sp will write the execution inforamtion into JobHistory table.

Answer (score 0):

As Akhil said, simply add a step in your job and ensure that it is chained correctly (assuming your job chains steps based on success only, on the final step success, execute your stored proc).

Comment: This method cannot get the history of current running job. Thanks.